# Probable mistake in a vector calculus problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

F is the vector $(e^y - \cos zx,0,z \cos zx)$. The question asks me to express this vector as a curl of another vector. Now if F is the curl of another vector V, then div curl V is 0 which implies that div F is 0 but here, clearly div F is not 0. So, I think the question has a mistake.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: A horrendously bad problem.

Comment: This was a question in yesterday's take home test. And it had 9 marks.

Comment: Naturally - cough <covid free>  - you did not submit this question here until AFTER the exam was over.